# Count how many rows are in the dataset then display as text in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset, count

How can I count how many rows are returned by a dataset and then show the total number of rows as textbox.text and read-only so that the user can only see them but not change them?

so far I have this but it dosent return a number and says it cant find table 0:

```
tbRecordsFound.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
```

Comment: What does "it dosent work for some reason" mean, do you get any errors?

Comment: It gets an error and says, "cant find table 0"

Comment: sounds like your dataset doesn't contain any tables.

Comment: So you have to add this DataTable with ds.Tables.Add(myDataTable): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection.add%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I fixed it. I was trying to count before I filled my Dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
tbRecordsFound.Text = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Sum(x => x.Rows.Count).ToString()
```

You can also do it like this:

```
Dim recordCount as Integer = 0;
For Each table as Datatable in ds.Tables
    recordCount += table.Rows.Count
tbRecordsFound.Text = recordCount.ToString()
```

Comment: @MDL: See LINQ example for something even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
tbRecordsFound.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
```

The above code will work, however you need to give the table an identifier, such as:

```
tbRecordsFound.Text = ds.Tables("TableName").Rows.Count
```

This can be done via creating a DataAdapter and using the "Fill" function to give the table a name. Here is an example where "da" represents the DataAdapter:

```
da.Fill(ds, "TableName")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To yourdatagridviewName.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
        i = +i
        TextBox2.Text = i 
    Next
```